# Error 400: unable to create collection using Firestore rest API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a collection inside FIRESTORE by making a REST API call.

My current URL for this request is:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/(default)/documents/?collectionId=<new-collection>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The requested URL /v1/projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/(default)/documents/?collectionId=grofers was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

I'm not sure if this is the way REST API calls for creating a collection has to be made. I tried looking at the docs and came back without finding much help.

What I'm trying to acheive:

1. Create a collection with a custom name

Any help on this matter is highly appreciated

Comment: Changed ALL CAPS - seen as SHOUTING at us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Firestore we don't create a Collection as such. A new Collection is created when the first Document of this Collection is created.

So for creating a doc in a new `abcd` collection, according to the [REST API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument), you need to call the following URL (see `abcd` at the end of the URL)

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/(default)/documents/abcd
```

with a POST request and the request body shall contain an instance of a [`Document`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document).

Comment: Yes: `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/(default)/documents/abcd/documentId/subcollection`

Comment: You may consider upvoting my answer when you'll have the reputation which allows it.